# jQuery Mobile - $.mobile.activePage.attr() call twice on initialisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to build a redirect after a initial startup splash screen with jQuery Mobile. The JavaScript code I have:

```
$(window).on('pageshow', function() {
       if($.mobile.activePage.attr("id") === "intro"){
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log($.mobile.activePage.attr("id"));
                $.mobile.changePage('pages/login.html');
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
```

For some reason, when I call the app the first time, I get two calls on this function with `console.log($.mobile.activePage.attr("id"));` outputting the ID of the **current page** (as it should) *and* on the second call the **ID of the following page**. I have no Idea why the if clause is not evaluating to fales and the code is called again. The IDs are set correctly are not duplicated at any time. Even more suprisingly, the demo case I built works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/AT5Fg/

Comment: try this `$('#intro').off('pageshow').on('pageshow', function() { code });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the implementation you posted, the pageshow event fires twice with `$.mobile.activePage.attr("id")` equal to `intro` which means that on both fires the `intro` page is active.

Analyzing the events on firebug shows that the event's target is different in these two fires. The event's target shows the element that registered for the event or a descendant of it.

On the first fire the event's target is the `div id = "intro"` element. On the second fire the event's target is the `ownerDocument` (top-level document object) of the `div id = "intro"`. But on both fires the mobile active page is the intro page. That's why you're facing this issue. If you perform a check using the `event.target.id == 'intro'` expression your code inside the if block will execute once.

[image]

[image]

Having analyzed the above I think you can resolve this issue using:

```
$(window).on('pageshow', function(event) {
   if(event.target.id === "intro"){
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log($.mobile.activePage.attr("id"));
            $.mobile.changePage('pages/login.html');
        }, 2000);
    }
})
```

or

```
$( document ).on( "pageshow", "#intro", function( event, ui ) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log($.mobile.activePage.attr("id"));
        $.mobile.changePage('pages/login.html');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks you for your detailed answer! Not only did you help to fix my problem, be also showed me what is causing the problem, which is always great to know and understand! Have a +1!